# Blpapi 'ignore_security_error=1' is an unexpected keyword

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I'm getting "ref() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_security_error'" when using ignore_security_error=1 with Blpapi. I have some bad tickers in my list i want to ignore using ignore_security_error=1 but getting an error. tc3 is a ticker list generated from a .csv file.

```
 M2= con.ref(tc3,["PX_LAST","CONTRACT_VALUE","CHG_PCT_1YR","CHG_PCT_6M","CHG_PCT_3M","CHG_PCT_1M","FO211","MARKET_SECTOR_DES","ID_BB_COMPANY"],ignore_security_error=1)
```

any one else having this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: from xbbg import blp
In [2]: tc3 = ...
In [3]: flds = [...]
In [4]: m2 = blp.bdp(tickers=tc3, flds=flds).dropna(how='all')
```

Reference: [xbbg](https://github.com/alpha-xone/xbbg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is requesting a list of tuples for overrides. Try passing it in like

```
 M2= con.ref(tc3,["PX_LAST","CONTRACT_VALUE","CHG_PCT_1YR","CHG_PCT_6M","CHG_PCT_3M","CHG_PCT_1M","FO211","MARKET_SECTOR_DES","ID_BB_COMPANY"],[('ignore_security_error', 1)])
```

*See https://github.com/matthewgilbert/pdblp/blob/master/pdblp/pdblp.py#L322*

*Note* It may take in True instead of 1. If this code does not work, try replacing it.

Comment: I used both 1 and True and get the error  "string indices must be integers", but this did eliminate the original error.

Comment: I'm using Pdblp not Blpapi to call the Bloomberg fields and the ovrds 'ignore_security_error=1' is not valid using Pdblp package.